# Getting many HTTP requests from a PC on my network

Tags: docker, http, flask, networking

I've got a flask REST api in a docker container hosted on a machine on my network with a certain port exposed and all is working fine, except that for some reason in the container logs I see hundreds of the following requests from a local IP that belongs to my desktop. I *do* use this desktop to ssh into the service machine to manage the services on there, so I was thinking perhaps vscode or one of my terminal instances might be causing this. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

```
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 09:56:38] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 16:36:19] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 16:36:25] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 16:36:55] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 19:56:35] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 21:10:11] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 21:22:48] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 21:22:52] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [31/Jan/2022 21:27:46] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.142 - - [01/Feb/2022 01:47:19] "GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: It might be someone/something looking for an exploitable UPnP router: https://cyware.com/news/hackers-could-exploit-well-known-upnp-protocol-flaw-to-launch-new-powerful-ddos-attacks-a61bdfe5

Comment: Hmm, I see. It doesn't look like there's much for me to do in that case?

Comment: You say that it's coming from a local IP address. In that case, that machine might have been compromised. If it's coming from the Internet, then there's not much you can do except make sure that you're not vulnerable.